# How to pass "this" and another variable in EventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a function in my addEventListener (#btn-1) that I want to remove eventually. I know that saving the function to a variable is the way to do it, but passing the "this" won't work unless it's wrapped in a function, which in turn won't be able to be removed now because it's either an anonymous function or it's not a reference to the same function even if it's named. Is there any way to do this?

```js
const anonFunction = function(dis, str) {
  console.log(dis);
  console.log(str);
}

const myFn = function() {
  anonFunction(this, 'hello world');
}

document.querySelector('#btn-1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  anonFunction(this, 'hello world');
});

document.querySelector('#btn-2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // doesn't work
  document.querySelector('#btn-1').removeEventListener('click', anonFunction);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" type="button">Call Function</button>
<button id="btn-2" type="button">Remove Event Listener</button>
```

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

Making another function calling the main function assigned to a variable and having that as the function to insert on adding and removing event listeners worked.

```js
const anonFunction = function(dis, str) {
  console.log(dis);
  console.log(str);
}

const myFn = function() {
  anonFunction(this, 'hello world');
}

document.querySelector('#btn-1').addEventListener('click', myFn);

document.querySelector('#btn-2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#btn-1').removeEventListener('click', myFn);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" type="button">Call Function</button>
<button id="btn-2" type="button">Remove Event Listener</button>
```

Comment: "*I know that saving the function to a variable is the way to do it,*" it is. And I don't see how the rest of the sentence has any relevance. Extract the function as, say, `myFn`  then use it for adding `.addEventListener("click", myFn)` and removing the listener `.removeEventListener("click", myFn)`

Comment: @VLAZ i need to pass arguments to the function, the "this" and a string

Comment: So? `const myFn = function() { anonFunction(this, 'hello world'); }` is still the way to extract it. What you do inside the function is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah I get it now and it solved my problem. I updated the post showing the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @teduniq Solutions should be posted in answers, not the question. You're allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: @Barmar I see. My bad then. I'll remember it next time as there's already another user who posted the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name your function that uses `this`.

```js
const anonFunction = function(dis, str) {
  console.log(dis);
  console.log(str);
}

const listener = function() {
  anonFunction(this, 'hello world');
};

document.querySelector('#btn-1').addEventListener('click', listener);

document.querySelector('#btn-2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // doesn't work
  document.querySelector('#btn-1').removeEventListener('click', listener);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" type="button">Call Function</button>
<button id="btn-2" type="button">Remove Event Listener</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you name your functions and be mindful of scope you can:

- run functions nested in event handlers
- pass the event object and separate parameters as well
- can `removeEventListener()`

By passing the Event Object:

```
echo(' From A ', e) 
/* Event Object ⬆️ is passed by default by all event handlers.
Commonly used variables are e, evt, and event */
```

We can use the `.target` property which always references the origin of event, or in layman's terms, the tag that the user interacted with. (*ex. the `<button>` the user clicked, the `<input>` the user typed data into, the `<area>` the user mouseovered, etc.*)

```
let msg = `This data was transferred from ${e.target.tagName}.${e.target.className}`
/* Reference to e.target passed from one event handler to another 
still maintains the same reference */
```

while `e.target` is reliable, there are some events that do not reference event origin in a useful way like for instance the "submit" event. A "submit" when triggered will reference the `<form>` as `e.target` not the *submit `<button>`*.

In this particular situation, `this` will be lost and will be `undefined`. At that point, we can call `echo(string, e)` and reestablish what `this` points to:

```
echo(text, e); // Delegated to .B

echo.call(this, ' From A ', e); // Delegated to .A
```

In the example when `.B` is clicked `this` is `undefined` and when `.A` is clicked, `this` points to `.A` even though both `.A` and `.B` were bound to the same event handlers.

```js
document.querySelector('.A').addEventListener('click', named);
document.querySelector('.B').addEventListener('click', named);

function named(e) {
  if (this.matches('.B')) {
    const text = this.textContent;
    echo(text, e);
  }
  if (this.matches('.A')) {
    echo.call(this, ' From A ', e);
  }
}

function echo(string, e) {
  let msg = `This data was transferred from ${e.target.tagName}.${e.target.className}
  ECHO: ${string.repeat(12)}
  Who is this? ${this.className}`;
  document.querySelector('.X').value = msg;
}

document.querySelector('.C').addEventListener('click', unbind);

function unbind(e) {
  document.querySelector('.A').removeEventListener('click', named);
}
```

```html
<button class='A' type="button">A</button>
<button class='B' type="button">B</button>
<textarea class='X' rows='5' cols='50'></textarea>
<button class='C' type="button">C - Click to Unbind A &amp; B</button>
```